# Casting a very large number to NULL in a query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm trying to retrieve the data from a snowflake database. But when I queried the data, it is failing stating "`Failed to cast variant value {numberLong: -8301085358432}`". From the error, I understood, that the values in my SQL query has a very long number.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT price,
       total_price,
       quantity
From Table1
```

Any one of the above three quantities may have the long number. How do I solve this `numberLong` error. Is there a way to cast that value to NULL if the value is too long.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL you are using to extract it?

Comment: I have no Snowflake knowledge, but in Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, and Postgres, there is no shortcut to narrowing down the field; to figure out which column is generating the error, I would comment out the other columns and go through them one at a time to locate the column containing the error, and from there find a way to view the sorted data to determine the erroneous value and fix it directly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using snowflake

Comment: Are you sure you shared the whole error message?

Comment: My guess is that your underlying data is a variant, and either in a view or somewhere you are trying to cast the value to something else.  It would be helpful if you could provide the data types of the underlying columns, as well as the ddl if it is a view

Comment: Is the table a regular Snowflake table, or an external table (based on files stored in S3 or GCS)? If it's an external table that might explain the fact that it looks like a table but is generating an error like that, it could be a problem with the external table definition which has defined data types for the columns that don't match the underlying data. When you SELECT from the external table it's trying to convert the file data to the defined data type and failing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think the error message is not complete. To reproduce the error, I run the following commands:

```
create table testv ( v variant);

insert into testv select '{numberLong: -8301085358432}'::variant;

create view dbt_likes_views as select to_decimal(v) price from testv;

select price
from dbt_likes_views;
```

*Failed to cast variant value "{numberLong: -8301085358432}" to FIXED*

If this is the case, then you need to check that data in your variant column.

Comment: So one of your variant columns contains that data: {numberLong: -8301085358432}. Check which of your columns are variant, and then look for this error. You tagged DBT, so I assume that your use DBT. DBT creates views for tables, maybe one of these views is converting variant column to number.